# ActionBar Tabs - Fixed and Scrollable?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

In the [Android Design Guidelines](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html#elements) it states that *"There are two types of tabs: fixed and scrollable."*

I can't find any documentation in the [ActionBar documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs) to support the ability to specify either type of tabs.

How do you specify a tab group to be fixed or scrollable? If you can't, what governs whether the tabs are fixed or scrollable exactly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The number of tabs dictates whether the tab group is fixed or scrollable. For example, if you have one tab, they'll be fixed but if you have like six then they'll become scrollable because all six can't fit on one screen.

If you want to see it in action on a pre-3.0 device, [download the Action Bar Sherlock sample](http://actionbarsherlock.com/download.html) and select Feature Toggles from the main list and then select "Tabs" as your navigation mode. Now you can add tabs to the bar and at first, they'll get smaller to cram them all in and then once you have enough you can scroll through them.

**UPDATE:** There is now a page on this in the official documentation that says "Fixed tabs are displayed with equal width, based on the width of the widest tab label. If there is insufficient room to display all tabs, the tab labels themselves will be scrollable." [Read more here.](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/tabs.html)

Comment: The design documentation suggests that it's possible to specify whether you're using scrollable or fixed tabs. Unfortunately with the action bar you have no control whatsoever whether they are fixed/scrollable even if you start modifying tab graphic size etc. You're right, it's down to screen width basically.

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that the setting

```
    android:showAsAction
```

will also have an effect on how tabs are shown, at least in 4.0+ devices.  Setting

```
        <item name="android:showAsAction">always</item>
```

as part of a theme will result in all tabs being given equal spacing on the screen, without scrolling, if space is available to do so.

Comment: This is part of the menu.xml file(s).  The setting had an effect on a device I was testing on, but if I remember correctly it did not solve the problem in all cases on all devices.  So your milage may very on this one.  Good luck!

Comment: I still don't get it. Where/How do you use Menu files for tabs ? I use them only f1SnapBook = actionBar.newTab()
        .setText(R.string.snapbook)
//    .setIcon(R.drawable.tab_snapbook)
    .setTabListener(this)
    .setTag(0);

Comment: I'm sorry, my previous comment is erroneous - this is an old post and I wasn't paying attention.  I'll update my original example with a better explanation.  This is part of themes, (styles.xml) not menu xmls.  Keep in mind that this might not actually help you.  In many cases I have simply simulated a tab bar using buttons to get that equal size effect.

Comment: @deepwinter style "Theme.AppCompat" does not have attribute by name "android:showAsAction"