# Action Bar with Fixed Tabs

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-tabhost, android-actionbar

Right now in my application I have a [`TabActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html) with three fixed tabs each of them containing a standard `Activity`.

Here is the relative code snippet:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.tab_activity);

    Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
    TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

    // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Tab1Activity.class);

    // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Tab 1", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.Tab1Icon)).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    // Do the same for the other tabs
    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Tab2Activity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Tab 2", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.Tab2Icon)).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Tab3Activity.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator("Tab 3", res.getDrawable(R.drawable.Tab3Icon)).setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    tabHost.setCurrentTab(0);
}
```

In this way each time I select a Tab the application will show on screen the `Activity` associated to that that tab.

I'd like to use the [`ActionBar`](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html#considerations-split-action-bars) design pattern to obtain the same result.

For now I'm just interested in having the fixed tab layout as you can see [here](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html#elements):

[image]

How should I change my code?

These SO questions did not help much:

- [ActionBar Tabs - Fixed and Scrollable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10243945/actionbar-tabs-fixed-and-scrollable)
- [ActionBar Tabs with multiple fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216108/actionbar-tabs-with-multiple-fragments)
- [Customizing ActionBar Tabs on Android 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10272812/customizing-actionbar-tabs-on-android-4)

Comment: Are you using API 14 as minimum?

Comment: @Se_bastiaan - In my current version no, but I'd like to write a new version supporting API 14.

Answer (score 2):

> In this way each time I select a Tab the application will show on screen the Activity associated to that that tab.

This approach is officially deprecated.

> I'd like to use the ActionBar design pattern to obtain the same result. How should I change my code?

The most straightforward approach is to convert those nested activities to fragments, then commit `FragmentTransaction`s as the selected tab changes. If you are using the native API Level 11 action bar, you can use the native API Level 11 `Fragment` class and the `FragmentTransaction` passed into your `TabListener`. If you wish to use ActionBarSherlock, you will wind up using the `Fragment` and `FragmentTransaction` from the Android Support package.

Comment: Could you please post some code snippets for better understanding the structure of the code I should write?thks in advance!